# How to distribute dict() periodically from a daemonic process to multiple threads? (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a looping daemonic thread receiving data from a web-socket updating a dict() with values. The daemonic process must continuously run updates to keep data in realtime. However, my other threads (varying from 1-15 other threads or processes) only need periodic updates. How can I get the dict() from the daemon thread and distribute the dict() periodically to the many other threads or processes? Is there an easy way to do this I am missing? Thanks in advance.

My example code that unreliably supplies one thread the dict using locks:

```
import time
import threading as t
from datetime import datetime

def updater(mydict,period,m):

    while True:
        # Continualy updates data to dict from websocket here

        data = int(str(datetime.now())[17:19]) # Test Data

        # Every 5 seconds: updates manager dict (unreliable)
        if int(str(datetime.now())[17:19])%period == 0:
            mydict['data'] = data
            m.release()
            time.sleep(1)


def calculator(mydict,period,m):

    # Every loop calls fresh data and does calculations
    while True:
        m.acquire()
        data = mydict

        # Calculations here.

        # Printing test code here.
        print ("Time: ", int(str(datetime.now())[17:19]))
        print ("Data: ", data)
        time.sleep(period)

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    m = t.Lock()
    m.acquire()
    dict = {}
    period = 5
    bot_process = t.Thread(target= updater, args= (dict,period,m))
    update_process = t.Thread(target= calculator, args= (dict,period,m))
    update_process.daemon = True
    update_process.start()
    bot_process.start()
```

For that code to work it would mean there would be one to one updater to calculator, however I would like there to only be one updater for all calculators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `calculator` function is only *reading* from the dict, and not writing to it.  This should be absolutely fine to do across as many threads as you want.  You can do away with the lock entirely in this case.

If you want to go for a more mature solution, though; I'd suggest looking into using a database.  `updater` can create entries in a table, and `calculator` can act upon them.  Database engines are meant to be used by many connections at once while remaining consistent, so the problem is now out of your hands.

Comment: You're right the lock was indeed not needed. I will look into databases, can you point me towards the simplest engine for this task? Thank you!

Comment: MySQL is undoubtedly the simplest, with the best tooling.